# How to have all the dataframe columns included

Tags: python, pandas

I have a concern here.
What I have programmed can do this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'STREAM':['EAGLE','HAWK','NORTH','HAWK','EAGLE','HAWK','NORTH'],'MAT':['A','D','F','D','C','C','E'],'KIS':['B','D','E','D','A','C','D']})

columns = ["A","B","C","D","E", "F"]

a = (pd.crosstab(df.STREAM,df.MAT, margins=True, margins_name='TOTAL').iloc[:,:-1].reindex(columns, axis=1, fill_value=0).rename_axis(None))
saved = a.to_csv(index=False)
a['TOT'] = a.sum(axis=1)
a['MEAN'] = a.mean(axis=1).round(2)
def x(i):
    if i >5:
        grade='A'
    else:
        grade='E'
    return grade
a['GRD'] = a.MEAN.apply(x)
print(a)
```

This gets me a result of

```
MAT    A  B  C  D  E  F  TOT  MEAN GRD
EAGLE  1  0  1  0  0  0    2  0.57   E
HAWK   0  0  1  2  0  0    3  0.86   E
NORTH  0  0  0  0  1  1    2  0.57   E
TOTAL  1  0  2  2  1  1    7  2.00   E
```

This is near what I want but there's one problem, only MAT is included. Could I have a way of including the total observations for both 'MAT' and 'KIS'in the table and also have the name 'MAT' on the top left corner of my table removed(blank)?

EDITS
Expected output

```
       A  B  C  D  E  F  TOT  MEAN GRD
EAGLE  2  1  1  0  0  0    4  0.??   E
HAWK   0  0  2  4  0  0    6  0.??   E
NORTH  0  0  0  1  2  1    4  0.??   E
TOTAL  2  1  3  5  2  1   14  ??     E
```

Comment: can you post the expected output too for clarity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
a = (pd.crosstab(df['STREAM'], df['MAT'], margins=True, margins_name='TOTAL').iloc[:,:-1].reindex(columns, axis=1, fill_value=0).rename_axis(None))
b = (pd.crosstab(df['STREAM'], df['KIS'], margins=True, margins_name='TOTAL').iloc[:,:-1].reindex(columns, axis=1, fill_value=0).rename_axis(None))
c = pd.concat([a, b], axis=1, join='inner')
d = c.groupby(lambda x:x, axis=1).sum()
d['TOT'] = d[columns].sum(axis=1)
d['MEAN'] = d[columns].mean(axis=1).round(2)
print(d)

def x(i):
    if i >5:
        grade='A'
    else:
        grade='E'
    return grade
d['GRD'] = d.MEAN.apply(x)
```

**Output:**

```
       A  B  C  D  E  F  TOT  MEAN GRD
EAGLE  2  1  1  0  0  0    4  0.67   E
HAWK   0  0  2  4  0  0    6  1.00   E
NORTH  0  0  0  1  2  1    4  0.67   E
TOTAL  2  1  3  5  2  1   14  2.33   E
```

Comment: The overall mean shouldn't be 4.00 but (1.14+1.71+1.14)/3

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to change the shape of you dataframe before doing the `crosstab`. Here is one way with `melt` and `pivot_table` instead of `crosstab` (mostly because I'm unsure how to use this method yet):

```
a = df.melt(id_vars=['STREAM'], value_vars=['MAT','KIS'])\
      .pivot_table(index='STREAM', columns='value', values='variable', 
                   aggfunc='count', fill_value=0, margins=True, margins_name='TOTAL')\
      .rename_axis(columns=None)\
      .rename(columns={'TOTAL':'TOT'})
a['MEAN'] = a.iloc[:,:-1].mean(axis=1).round(2)
a["GRADE"] = np.where(a['MEAN']> 5, 'A', 'E')
print (a)
        A  B  C  D  E  F  TOT  MEAN GRADE
STREAM                                   
EAGLE   2  1  1  0  0  0    4  0.67     E
HAWK    0  0  2  4  0  0    6  1.00     E
NORTH   0  0  0  1  2  1    4  0.67     E
TOTAL   2  1  3  5  2  1   14  2.33     E
```

Comment: There has been a duplicate of totals but I've eliminated it. How comes the mean at the final mean is not true?

Comment: Yes, that's what it should be, the mean

Comment: Okay. I'll appreciate much

Comment: @Ptar done, remove duplicated total and rename the column from TOTAL to TOT and change the way to get the mean to exclude the TOT column from it, hope it is better what you want